# Build dynamic pivot query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have this query which has the following output:

```
SELECT o.date      AS Date, 
       u.firstname AS FirstName, 
       u.lastname  AS LastName, 
       m.name      AS MealName 
FROM   catering.user u 
       LEFT JOIN catering.order o 
              ON u.iduser = o.iduser 
       LEFT JOIN catering.meal m 
              ON m.idmeal = o.idmeal 
WHERE  o.weeknumber = 37 
GROUP  BY u.firstname, 
          o.date 
ORDER  BY o.date;
```

[image]

What I need is to write a query to get the following output:
[image]

I followed the other posts related with the dynamic pivot query, but MySql is a new topic for me and I can't figure out how to use the prepared statement in my case?

The error message i get is:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

I am using MySql Workbench 6.0 CE

Comment: How many different names do you have?

Comment: @Mihai I have more than 30 different names

Comment: @Mihai I get the following error on running the query: `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT date,SELECT date,MAX(CASE WHEN u.firstname= 'john' THEN  m.name END) AS j' at line 1 0.000 sec `

Comment: These type of query is kinda hard to write,especially if I have to do it blindly.Can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/  with some sample data?

Comment: @Mihai http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b920/3

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b920/8

Comment: I still get that error message :(

Comment: Can you post in your question the full error message?Oh btw,are you running the query in phpmyadmin?Because it`s a piece of crap, use http://www.heidisql.com/ instead.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` tells you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61704/discussion-between-laura-and-mihai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN firstname= ''',
      firstname,
      ''' THEN mealName END) AS ',
      firstname
    )
   )INTO @sql
FROM  
(SELECT o.date      AS Date, 
       u.firstname AS FirstName, 
       u.lastname  AS LastName, 
       m.name      AS MealName 
FROM   catering.user u 
       LEFT JOIN catering.order o 
              ON u.iduser = o.iduser 
       LEFT JOIN catering.meal m 
              ON m.idmeal = o.idmeal 
WHERE  o.weeknumber = 37 
GROUP  BY u.firstname, 
          o.date 
ORDER  BY o.date)x;



SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT date,',@sql,' FROM
(SELECT o.date      AS Date, 
       u.firstname AS FirstName, 
       u.lastname  AS LastName, 
       m.name      AS MealName 
FROM   catering.user u 
       LEFT JOIN catering.order o 
              ON u.iduser = o.iduser 
       LEFT JOIN catering.meal m 
              ON m.idmeal = o.idmeal 
WHERE  o.weeknumber = 37 
GROUP  BY u.firstname, 
          o.date 
ORDER  BY o.date)x  
GROUP BY date');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b920/8)